# Differences between the static variables of SSLSocketFactory

Tags: php, android

i'm implementing a web server in php and doing the connection to an android app,i'm using SSLSocketFactory so i what to now the differences between the static options of SSLSocketFactory:

1. STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
2. BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
3. ALLOW_ALL__HOSTNAME_VERIFIER

   ```
   DefaultHttpClient ret = null;
   //SETS UP PARAMETERS
   HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
   HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
   HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf-8");
   params.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

   //REGISTERS SCHEMES FOR BOTH HTTP AND HTTPS
   SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
   registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

   final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
   //final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();

   sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
   registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));

   ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
   return ret = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);
   ```

Comment: Could you be way more specific on what your actual question is?

Comment: Yes, i found the effect if i use SLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER essentially turns off hostname verification when using SSL connections. This is equivalent to trusting all certificates. but i whant to now the effect of using  STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER   and
BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER too